# reseting animator in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

im trying to do some simple animations of a moving ball when i click on it and i want to do it in a "loop" what i mean is when i click the first time the ball will move from point A to point B, after that to point C and then to point A again and if i will press again it will go to point B...

the problem is that after i finish the first rotation (the ball got to point A again) the ball wont go to point B no matter what.

this is the animator with the states and the state parameter the condition for moving from state to state is just an int that goes up by 1 from click to click and is restarted when it gets to 5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkgQF.png)

and this is the code that changes the state every time i click on it

```
  public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (relesed)
    {
        relesed = false;
        int temp = anim.GetInteger("state");
        temp++;
        anim.SetInteger("state", temp);
        if (anim.GetInteger("state") >= 5)
        {
            anim.SetInteger("state", 0);
            anim.ResetTrigger("state");
        }
        print(anim.GetInteger("state"));
    }

    meshRenderer.material.color = downColor;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be causing this, check on the transitions to make sure they are properly checking the integer you're working with. As for the code, it does what you want just fine. Code-wise it could be that the "relese" boolean is being set to false after the first loop.

Just a few notes regarding the code:
You're using anim.ResetTrigger("state") when "state" is not a trigger, it's an integer parameter. There are also some small performance issues for unecessary GetInteger calls, here's how I would improve it:

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (relesed)
        {
            relesed = false;
            int temp = anim.GetInteger("state");
            temp++;
            if (temp >= 5)
                temp = 0;
            
            anim.SetInteger("state", temp);

            print(temp);
        }

        meshRenderer.material.color = downColor;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the improvment of the code, for the fix part, i did try to follow the steps with the print part and it does change and resets, but notting happens after it finishs a full rotation

Comment: you need to check inside the animator itself, check it at runtime, it will show you which is the current animation, the values of the parameters, basically everything you need to find the problem